# How can I have a searchable ReactSelect component which displays/switches values based on the input value?

Tags: react-select

I have a dropdown that I have implemented using ReactSelect. It is searchable. But when I search, it queries for any value with the input string. Rather, I need a startswtih filter. If I type A, it should first go to the first filtered value that starts with A.

I tried using a filter on the handler for 'onInputChange' but it is not getting displayed on the dropdown

Comment: Could you provide an example of your code ? So we can help. thanks

Comment: I actually figure it out. Has a prop call filterOption which can be used to customize your filter.